# Parallel LINQ - .Select() + .ForAll() returning bizarre results

Tags: c#, plinq

For the life of me, I can't figure out why all the foos are not null.
I'm assuming the `.ForAll()` should be executing before I call the `.All()` method, but it's not?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foos = new List<Foo> { new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo() };
    var newFoos = foos
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(x =>
        {
            x.Bar = "";
            return x;
        });
    newFoos.ForAll(x => x = null);
    var allFoosAreNull = newFoos.All(x => x == null);
    Console.WriteLine(allFoosAreNull); // False ??
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this

```
newFoos.ForAll(x => x = null);
```

you are assigning `null` to `x`, which is the parameter of your lambda.  `x` is local to the lambda.  It is not a `ref` parameter, and assigning values to it has no effect outside of its body.  Effectively, that line does nothing.

Comment: Even if I modify the body of the lambda to set the `Bar` property to another value, that value doesn't stick either. I'm still a bit perplexed; I'm under the assumption that `ForAll()` is iterating over the actual list. In other words, why would the lambda *not* be `ref`?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this doesn't even have anything to do with PLINQ...it's the same behavior with `.ForEach()`.